# auto logout from second application when logout trigger from first application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logout, long-polling, pingfederate

Scenario: 
I have two application to which login is done using pingfederate single sign service. 
1.User try to login into first application but as user is unauthenticated user is redirected to login page of pingfederate (universal sign in page). User logs into the first application.
2.User try to login into second application as user was already authenticated by single sign service pingfederate provide application with necessary information(information required to set session) and user is redirected to second application.

Problem: 
When User logout from first application then user gets logout successfully. At this point pingfederate knows about all open application and send then logout callback. So it sends logout request to second application. Second application handles the logout request and clears the session. But user stays on the same page. user is not redirected to the login page
Question:
How can be this be implemented that when we receive logout request redirect user to login page?

Answer (score 0):

The way SLO is supposed to work for SP-Init SLO is:

1. You click logout at the FIRST SP application.
2. You are redirected to the IdP with a LogoutRequest.
3. The IdP then sends you, serially, to all the other SPs with
   LogoutRequests. Every one of those must provide a SAMLResponse back
   to the IdP with a status.
4. The IdP, after receiving the final status, must send the
   user/browser back to the originating SP with a SAMLResponse with the
   final status, which the SP acts upon.

In IdP-Init SLO, it's basically only step 3.

Here's the kicker, though, and I think gets to the heart of your question. If a single one of those SP's "misbehaves", i.e., does not respond to, or support, SLO (there is no requirement for them to support SLO), then it will break the "chain" of logouts, if you redirect to it! The IdP will redirect off to the SP, and the there the browser will stay. Once the chain has been broken, there is no way to get it started again.

I discussed this problem in my blog post ["SLO - Proceed With Caution"](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/blog/2013/12/02/slo_-_proceed_with_caution.html), a bit more than a year ago. Ultimately, with many of the big-name SP's out there not supporting SLO, there's not much of a reason to do it - it's just going to give you, as an SAML administrator, a black eye. Or heartburn. Or both.

Comment: I got this workflow. Same thing is happening here. My question is not about first application from which I have trigger the logout. I am talking about second application. I saw second applications server log it received the logout request from ping federate. It clears the session and then redirect to ping federate SP with given "Resume" parameter but this redirection is not displayed on the browser. For user it looks he is still on the same page.

Comment: This would be up to the SP application then - is there anything in the logs there?